# Use HttpListener with certificate in code. NOT using netsh or httpcfg

Tags: c#, https, httplistener

I have an app that consists of a fat client and extensions. The extensions can load html and communicate with the app using http request. Therefor my app listens on localhost to http requests.

To enable the app running on a terminal server environment, it cannot (as far as i see) use a fixed portnumber (because all instances will try to claim the same portnumber). So, on startup, it tries to open a HttpListener on random ports, untill it succeeds.

I now want to enable the pages to be loaded using http**S**. Using Netsh/httpcfg to bind a certificate to a fixed port is useless, because of the random port idea. I know it is actually possible with WCF to add a certificate in code. (setting the certificate on the Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate property and setting the binding correct)

Is this possible with a HttpListener?

I have the certificate and all setup - the question is only to dynamicly use that certificate on a non-fixed portnumber.

(And if it is, is it also possible to do the same with Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(...))